# errors installing gem "rumember" in Ubuntu 16.4 LTS

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I tried for several hours to get the rumember gem installed and running.

After a failed upgrade of my system to 16.4 Ubuntu LTS i had to reinstall the system completely (with 16.4. But now I cant get the rumember gem to work again.

I googled a lot and tried several approaches. e.g. I installed the ruby-dev package for headers and I ran sudo gem update --system 
and got "Latest version currently installed ..."

I see that the json version in the errors is 1.7.7 and in my system its 1.8.3. but i don't know if that matters.

Thats how far I got. Thanks for any Ideas on the topic.

**Update 1:** I just tried to install it on a fresh VM Ubuntu LTS 16.4. Install ruby, install ruby-dev, gem install rumember. Same problems occur. So it's not just my setup.

---

sudo gem install rumember

outputs:

```
    ERROR:  Error installing rumember:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20161214-5373-1y3th00.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:0:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function ‘fbuffer_to_s’:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: macro "rb_str_new" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
 VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                           ^
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:20: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                ^
Makefile:239: recipe for target 'generator.o' failed
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/json-1.7.7/gem_make.out
```

gem list outputs:

```
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.8)  
bundler (1.11.2) 
configuration (1.3.4) 
did_you_mean (1.0.0) 
diff-lcs (1.2.5) 
io-console (default: 0.4.5) 
json (default: 1.8.3) 
launchy (0.3.7) 
minitest (5.8.4) 
molinillo (0.4.3) 
net-http-persistent (2.9.4) 
net-telnet (0.1.1) 
power_assert (0.2.7) 
psych (default: 2.0.17) 
rake (10.5.0) 
rdoc (default: 4.2.1) 
rspec (3.5.0) 
rspec-core (3.5.4)
rspec-expectations (3.5.0) 
rspec-mocks (3.5.0) 
rspec-support (3.5.0) 
rubygems-update (2.0.3) 
test-unit (3.1.7) 
thor (0.19.1)
```

Comment: What is the minimum version of `json` that it requires?

Comment: Runtime Dependencies:
json ~> 1.7.0  
launchy ~> 0.3.0   ------
Development Dependencies:
rspec ~> 2.5 ------- I think that means at least 1.7.0. source: https://rubygems.org/gems/rumember/versions/1.0.1